# 'C:/Perl64/bin/' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, perl

I installed active perl on my win2k12 server, I want to run a perl script but it showing this message, 
'C:/Perl64/bin/' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
I change environment variable path like C:\Perl\bin,C:\Perl\site\bin,C:\Perl64\bin.
but what ever path i changed same path is not recognised as an internal or external command.

Comment: How do you run the perl script? By double click or from the command line? Where are your perl binaries actually installed?

Comment: i am running perl by command line. and my perl binaries are on this path C:\Perl64\bin.

Answer (score 0):

### A) the script to be run

#### a) Slashes

Have a look at the script you want to run. 
Most probably, the first line will look like

`#!C:/Perl/bin/`

or similar. Change the forward slashes to backslashes and try again.

#### b) Executable

Of course, the shebang above misses the executable binary. So if it is missing from your script, change it to

`#!C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe`

or

`#!C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe -w`

if you want to have Perl output warnings.

### B) your Perl installation

Have a look at `C:\Perl\bin\` and `C:\Perl64\bin\` respectively. Do both exist? If not, change the shebang in your script to

`#!C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe -w`

### C) Alternative

I was assuming that you simply run or double click `script.pl`. If you want to tell Windows to run that script with a certain application (Perl, in your case), run your script via

```
C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe -w C:\path\to\your\script.pl
```

Comment: thank you !!! I tried this all but its not working. this path I have C:\Perl64\bin\ . In environment variable C:\Perl64\bin;C:\Perl64\site\bin; this both path are there. I tried by changing there sequence. but its showing that  "C:\Perl64\bin" is not recognized as an internal or external command. path is whatever I set first path into environment variable.

Comment: That's interesting. Could you add at least the first couple lines, shebang and included modules of your Perl script to your question? Also, however I am sure that it does not matter, try to add a backslash to the end of the elements in your path: `C:\Perl64\bin\ `. Does your script run with  `C:\Perl64\bin\perl.exe -w C:\path\to\your\script.pl`?

Comment: Does it work as expected meanwhile? Or could you post the beginning of your Perl script here?

Comment: thank you so much you stueja for helping me a lot.my issue is solved.

Comment: Good to hear that.  Feel free to `accept the answer` if I could help you or let me know what else we could try.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was an environment variable issue. I was using Oracle 11g r2. and its path didn't have oracle name in it. I am searching "oracle" word from perl script into environment variable, but I was getting the first path which was perl path, so perl was failing to run. The issue is solved. Thank you so much, stueja.